# UK DATV transit visa form queries

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, h1b-visas, datv

Can anyone please help me in answering some questions for the UK DATV  form? 
For reference, I am an Indian national who would be travelling from US to India and back via UK Heathrow airport. My current H1B stamp expired on 1/31/2018 but have a valid I-797 till 1/31/2019.

My queries:

1. The form asks "What permission do you have to be in United States of America?", since my visa is expired but I have a valid I-797, I chose the option "do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident" and explained my situation. Is this the correct way?
2. The Travel information asks date of arrival and departure in UK. I will be visiting and departing UK for both side of my journeys so which date should I provide?
3. The form asks "Do you have a valid visa or residence permit for the country you are travelling to?" I have answered yes and provided my passport details when it asks "What is the reference number of your permit or visa to this country?". Is that correct?

Comment: Q2 - two separate journeys, two DATVs?

Comment: I-797 comes in various flavours which mean different things. What kind do you have? Is it extending your H1B or extending your permission to reside in the US? Will your I-797 grant you entry to the US? Have you applied for H1B extension?

Answer (score 1):

For the date of arrival and departure, I would enter the dates your flights will arrive and depart. They are almost certainly either the same day, or one day apart.

For whether you have a valid visa or residence permit, consider why the UK asks for certain information. They want to be satisfied that you are able to enter the country you are travelling *from*, in the unlikely event that they must refuse you entry and return you to that country. For this, they ask about whether you are a resident of that country.

If you have an I-797A with attached I-94, or I-797B, then you are approved to live and work in the US, but must also obtain a US visa (in this case H-1B) to actually travel there. You will return to India for visa stamping, then at some point in the future, back to the US.

To answer the question about your valid residence permit, I would enter your A number. This is the number tied to all of your US immigration, employment authorization, etc. This is the USCIS A# on your I-797, and on your EAD. Because these show you are authorized to live and work in the US, using the A number should be sufficient here. And UK visa officers are already familiar with the A number.